# What is the a block matrix representation of a density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I think the block representation means the covariance matrix here. But, why is there an equivalence class between the density matrix and covariance matrix? I have been reading a paper that uses this representation.

[image: The paragraph from the paper]

Also, what's the physical meaning of the Eigen values and eigenvectors of these submatrices here?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to P.SE - Inclusion of images heavy on text is not encouraged, please type in the relevant information to ask the question to keep the content searchable. Use MathJax/LaTeX to include formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer* : this has nothing to do with a covariance matrix.

*Long answer* :
When a vector space (Hilbert space in the case of QM) is written as a direct sum :
$$\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1 \oplus \mathcal H_2$$
any vector can be written uniquely $x = x_1 + x_2$ with $x_i \in \mathcal H_i\quad (i\in \{1,2\})$.

It can be useful to write $x  = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$, and we are not introducing any ambiguity by doing this.

Then, for any operator $A$ on $\mathcal H$, we can write :
$$Ax= \begin{pmatrix}A_{11} x_1 + A_{12}x_2 \\ A_{21} x_1 + A_{22} x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

with operators
\begin{align*}
A_{11} : \mathcal H_1 \to \mathcal H_1\\
A_{12} : \mathcal H_2 \to \mathcal H_1 \\
A_{21} : \mathcal H_1 \to \mathcal H_2\\
A_{22} : \mathcal H_2 \to \mathcal H_2
\end{align*}

This is just notations, but it behaves exactly like matrix algebra, excepts the coefficients of the matrix are themselves operators.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.